# Unable to Access files in Directory

Tags: java

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
DB_SET
 -D1
   - DB_1.txt
 -D2
   - DB_2.txt 
 -D3
   - DB_3.txt
 -D4
   - DB_4.txt
 -D5
   - DB_5.txt
```

I want to store all `DB_1.txt`, `DB_2.txt`, `DB_3.txt`, `DB_4.txt`, `DB_5.txt` in an `ArrayList`. How can I do this?
My Partial code:

```
File folder = new File("./WebContent/datasets/DB_Set/");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
System.out.println("listofFiles: "+listOfFiles);
ArrayList<File> sub_dir = new ArrayList<File>();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      }
    else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        sub_dir.add(listOfFiles[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't System.out printing the file names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go into 2 levels deep.

```
        File folder = new File("./WebContent/datasets/DB_Set/");
        File[] listOfSubDirectories = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.isDirectory();
            }
        });
        ArrayList<File> filesList = new ArrayList<File>();
        for (File dir : listOfSubDirectories) {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File file) {
                    return file.isFile();
                }
            });

            for (File f : files) {
                filesList.add(f);       
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a FileFilter that implements accept, something like

```
boolean accept(File pathname) {
    returns pathname != null && pathname.isFile();
}
```

and then call listFiles() with the filter

```
File[] files = folder.listFiles(my_file_filter);
```

and files should contain only the files.  If you need to make sure the file names all end with .txt (because there could be other files in the directories) then add a string check of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this would be to accumulate the files recursively:

```
private static List<String> addFiles (File dir) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            restult.addAll(addFiles(f));
        } else if (f.isFile()) {
            result.add(f.getName());
        } else { // Just in case it's not a file or directory
            // log or something
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    File folder = new File("./WebContent/datasets/DB_Set/");
    List<File> files = addFiles(folder);
}
```